Fire retardant/waterproofing
I have put up a new redwood fence. I want to use a fire retardant on both sides, clear with no color. Then I want to waterproof, clear with no color. Can I do this with one product, or is it possible to do with 2 products. Fireproof first, then waterproof?  I live in a high fire danger area.

If you live in a high fire danger area, I question the wisdom of putting up a wood fence in the first place, even with fire retardant as a possible option.

Well, you certainly wouldn't want to seal before fireproofing... Though I jiw no idea how much difference fireproofing a cedar fence would actually make.
